# Calculate height of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with a set height.

```
<div class="foo" style="height:100px;">bar</div>
```

Is it possible to find what the div's height would be if the height was not explicitly set by my style property?

In other words, I'd like to find the height of the following div without actually changing the div.

```
<div class="foo">bar</div>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery? You can get an element's height with jQuery $('.foo').outerHeight();

Comment: no jquery is necessary. see my answer below which uses the simple `clientHeight` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var clone = $('.foo').clone();
clone.css('height', 'auto');
clone.css('visibility', 'hidden');

$('body').append(clone);

console.log(clone.height());
```

Comment: Was about to write it, best way, but I think default value for height is auto;

Comment: @StevenWexler, would you like me to write a pure javascript version?

Comment: I just want to point out that not all browsers supports getting height of non visible elements.

Comment: Pretty sure it's meant to be *visibility* and not *visible*.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `clientHeight` property to get the inner height of the element. `clientHeight` is equivalent to the css `height` property. See the snippet below (the first line demonstrates the use of `clientHeight`):

```js
var height = document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0].clientHeight;

document.getElementById('heightOfFoo').innerHTML = height;
```

```html
<div class="foo">bar</div>

<div id="heightOfFoo"></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain how your answer gets the height of the modified div without style="height:100px".

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight. It's part of the CSS object model specification.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my question.  See @AmmarCSE's answer.

Comment: Based off your question, you want to get the height of a `div` element without modifying it or setting the `style`. My answer proposes a standard way that you can do this easily in one line of code by retrieving the element and then getting the `clientHeight` of that element.

Comment: I want to see what the height of my div would be _after_ a change has occurred without actually making the change to my element.  You answer only get the height of the element as it currently stands, not what the height of the element would be after modifications.

Comment: after a change has occured, you can just call `clientHeight` of the element to get its height after modifications...

Comment: The point is to get what the height will be _without_ modifying the element.    If you understand why @AmmarCSE's answer is correct, then I think you'll understand why your answer doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Okay. I am confused. First you are asking how to get the height after modifications. Then, you are asking how to get it without modifications. In either case, `clientHeight` gets the height of the element. It's merely accessing it and getting the `clientHeight` property of the target element.

Comment: If you understand why @AmmarCSE's answer is correct, then you'll understand what I'm asking.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jquery you can just grab the height with $('.target-class').height()

Comment: This gets the height of my div.  It doesn't get the height of my div with style=height:100px removed.

Comment: sorry, it seems to work for me. http://jsbin.com/pikutiqine/1/ might be something I'm missing

Comment: You are misunderstanding my question.  See @AmmarCSE's answer.

Comment: ok, that's fine. I guess I fail to see what exactly you are asking that I have not done in the jsbin link. glad you found your answer though.

Comment: I appreciate your response!  But you should delete your answer if it's wrong.

Comment: I don't believe it's wrong and it doesn't hurt leaving it.

Comment: What you've said is true, just like saying the earth is round is true.  But, your answer doesn't address the question.  So it's wrong.